# Use Parsec to write a new function "parse :: String -> Stm"

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, parsec, megaparsec

I have a coursework that requires me to write a new function parse:: String -> Stm. Parsec already has a parse function, so I'm supposed to import qualified parsec so that parse returns my wrapper function. 
The wrapper function needs to parse the input string to Parsec's parse function and unpack the result from the returned monad. This is the code for my wrapper function. 
How do I ensure that when parse is called, it returns my wrapper function.

```
parseString :: String -> Stm
parseString str =
   case parse procParser "" str of
     Left e  -> error $ show e
     Right r -> r
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “when parse is called”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do exactly what the instructions say:

```
import qualified Text.Parsec

parse :: String -> Stm
parse str =
  case Text.Parsec.parse procParser "" str of
    Left e  -> error $ show e
    Right r -> r
```